# Run Nginx with seperate configuration and seperate user

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I made a service that i been running on windows without problem and i started porting it to unix.

The service writes a dynamic nginx.conf file and one windows its been easy because it was just to launch nginx.exe -c nginx.conf

I am facing a few problems on ubuntu with permissions.

1. nginx was install with sudo: `sudo apt-get install -y nginx-extras`

after this its running a very simple http page on port 80. Which is fine. My config is using some other ports.

When my service run and try to run nginx for the new config file i get the following issue:

`nginx  -c "/mnt/sfroot/_sf_gateway/S-Innovations.ServiceFabric.GatewayApplication/nginx.conf"
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2018/09/24 13:32:42 [emerg] 5825#5825: mkdir() "/usr/share/nginx/cache/GatewayService" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

I can fix the cache by setting a location where it has permission. But no matter what i do, it keeps trying to write to /var/log/nginx/error.log.

How do i

1. Kill the default nginx service (if needed)
2. Run a new nginx service that dont need access to root user (sudo)

Comment: Has your new conf file got an `error_log` directive?

Comment: yes, but i keep reading elsewhere that even though, nginx will try to write the default error log.

Comment: At what level of your configuration have you placed your `error_log` directive?

Comment: THanks @miknik - you got me. i had it at http and should put it at main